# Using a publish profile with msbuild

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, msbuild

I'm trying to use a publish profile with the `msbuild` command in a PowerShell window on a machine that does not have the full Visual Studio IDE installed. I have tried the following:

```
msbuild.exe .\Web.Admin.csproj /p:'DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=Default;'
MSBuild.exe .\Web.Admin.csproj /p:PublishProfile=Default /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0
msbuild.exe .\Web.Admin.csproj /p:PublishProfileRootFolder=C:\Users\username\Projects\Web\Web.Admin\Properties\PublishProfiles  /p:PublishProfile=Default
```

In both cases, the publish profile seems to be ignored. This is the publish profile, generated by Visual Studio (in `Properties\PublishProfiles\Default.pubxml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
This file is used by the publish/package process of your Web project. You can customize the behavior of this process
by editing this MSBuild file. In order to learn more about this please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>True</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>C:\Sites\Test</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <PrecompileBeforePublish>True</PrecompileBeforePublish>
    <EnableUpdateable>True</EnableUpdateable>
    <DebugSymbols>False</DebugSymbols>
    <WDPMergeOption>DonotMerge</WDPMergeOption>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

The files are not published to the `C:\Sites\Test` directory specified, as they would be if I ran this with the **Publish** command in Visual Studio 2017. Instead they go to the project `bin` directory.

MSBuild Version: 14.0.23107.0

Comment: Please add: which version of msbuild are you using (`msbuild /version`), what distributable you installed (VS 2015, 2017, Full / Build Tools) and how you ran powershell (Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio?)

Comment: @MartinUllrich I added the MSBuild version and clarified I am running PowerShell on a machine without Visual Studio installed. I'm actually not sure exactly how MSBuild got onto this machine, I assume it was installed as part of the WebDeploy package or some other IIS feature. This is a Windows 2016 Server.